# Makefile error make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2

Tags: windows, bash, git, pip

I am using a Makefile to setup [MultiNet](https://github.com/MarvinTeichmann/MultiNet) and followed the steps given. But when I use the make function it throws the follwoing error:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/natMg.png)

My makefile contains the following code:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
$(info $(SHELL))
.PHONY: all
all:
    pip install runcython
    makecython++ stitch_wrapper.pyx "" "stitch_rects.cpp ./hungarian/hungarian.cpp"
```

I tried to look for a lot of solutions but the best I could find was git/bin not being a path variable but even on adding it nothing changes.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: How is "The system cannot find the file specified" unclear? Why is `"stitch_rects.cpp ./hungarian/hungarian.cpp"` quoted? I doubt you have a single file with that name

Comment: You did not say which bash implementation you are using. Is it one which allows backslashes as path separator?